# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'long org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration - spark/Scala/sbt assembly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, sbt

I have kept same version of jars of buildsbt under the path /opt/spark/jars/
Created assembly jar using sbt and executing the jar using spark-submit and getting the above error. How can we know that which jar/class file is throwing the error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'long org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(java.lang.String, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$HookEntry.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.java:207)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.java:304)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.install(ShutdownHookManager.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks$lzycompute(ShutdownHookManager.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks(ShutdownHookManager.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.createTempDir(Utils.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:898)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'long org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(java.lang.String, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.shutdownExecutor(ShutdownHookManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.access$300(ShutdownHookManager.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:102)

**build.sbt**

name := "xyz"
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.2.1"


assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Comment: Try adding `hadoop-client` dependency

Comment: Thanks, it fixed but now getting different error (tried adding also removing the jars guava-16.0.1.jar  guava-31.1-jre.jar but still the same error )                           Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1357)

Comment: That's a different error than posted. Yes, you'll need guava, don't remove it. By the way, you should add `% "provided"` to Spark core and sql dependencies. And are you actually running the jar with spark-submit rather than just `java jar`?